# I no longer receive sms from services (bank, google otp, confirmation throught sms, ...)

Tags: sms, huawei, bugs, google-messages

I found myself in a really strange problem, I have not received text messages from services for several months, while I continue to receive any other type of text message (e.g. if a friend of mine sends me a text message I receive it and I can also reply, but if I register somewhere and I receive a confirmation SMS, or if I have to make a payment with my credit card and receive the OTP from my bank, and other such messages are not received).
I use the google messaging app as an SMS app, I disabled spam protection for the test but nothing seems to have changed.
In the advanced section of the settings of the "Google messages" app I have:

- receive service messages: enabled
- the entry "phone number" is filled in with my phone number
- the "Custom SMSC" item is filled in with the SMSC provided by my telephone operator

I tried to:

- reset the network settings and restart
- turn off and on again (removing the sim)
- delete all SMS
- Boot in safe mode
- insert the SIM on another mobile phone (it works)

know that android StackExchange is my last hope, I spent 2 days talking to my telephone operator who did nothing but give me solutions such as: switch off and on, buy a new phone, or "we don't take care of it, call your device manufacturer "
I then call Huawei (I have a Huawei P20 Pro) and I am told that the problem is not theirs as "Huawei is just one of many brands and they do not add particular SMS blocks to their devices other than those of any other mobile", and then to call my telephone operator again.

I hope to find a solution here at least, thanks in advance to those who want to help me.

```
Huawei P20 Pro (CLT-L09), EMUI 10.0.0, Android 10
```

Comment: Reinstalling com.google.android.gms solved my problem:
`adb shell cmd package install-existing com.google.android.gms`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138093/discussion-on-question-by-loris-simonetti-i-no-longer-receive-sms-from-services).